# OVP threshold for this converter

Tags: voltage, current, buck, boost, over-voltage-protection

Here, this [Boost converter](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic2253.pdf), says that it can boost the input voltage from 2.5 V to 10 V.

My input is from a 7.4 V, 7.5 Ah battery. Output is 9 V. The maximum load current is 3 A.

Ideally, for my OVP feature to work, I need to keep the resistor divider such that the OVP threshold value is more than 9 V, right? But according to the electrical characteristics table, the maximum value of OVP is 6.3 V.

Does it makes sense, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, so make sure your divided value at 9+ V is 6.3 at the OVP pin?

Comment: @winny, could you please explain a little more? If my output voltage is higher than the 6.3V, it doesn't make sense to have the OVP feature, right? How will OVP work then if its maximum value is only 6.3V, when my output is 9V?

Comment: Because your voltage divider will divide it down, effectively raising the OVP to something higher than 6.3 V.

Comment: Refer to the OVP section on page 8 of the datasheet, it explains it quite clearly.

Answer (score 1):

> *Ideally, for my OVP feature to work, I need to keep the resistor
> divider such that the OVP threshold value is more than 9V, right? But
> according to the electrical characteristics table, the maximum value
> of OVP is 6.3V.*

The OVP threshold is typically 5.6 volts and might be as high as 6.3 volts or, as low as 5.25 volts. So, to prevent the normally expected 9 volt output tripping the OVP (a safety mechanism to protect the output and load), you need to ensure that the resistive divider from the 9 volt output to the OVP input is just below 5.25 volts: -

[image]

So, if the output rose to (say) 9.05 volts, the OVP would trip. However, because you cannot be sure of the OVP threshold, the output might have to rise to 10.8 volts. So, you have to decide whether 10.8 volts on the output is too much and, if it is, you'll have to use select-on-test resistors in the resistive divider to ensure the OVP trip comes in at slightly above 9.0 volts. From the [data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic2253.pdf): -

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Let me just check on this and come back.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. The OVP divider is no different from the FB divider, just a higher setpoint:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLv0q2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the datasheet isn't very clear on the OVP pin as much as the FB pin, right?

Comment: @Newbie What struck me was the extremely wide tolerance on the OVP setpoint in the datasheet.

Comment: Yes, I feel the datasheet is quite misleading on this point.